# 毎日同じ時刻にJavaScriptを実行するには？

Tags: javascript, node.js

現在Node.jsとline notify apiを使ってlineにメッセージを送るようにしています。リマインダーのような仕組みです。

**今定期実行する仕組みを考えているのですが、どのようなツールがおすすめとかありますでしょうか？**
定期的にNode.jsを命令するような仕組みがあればいいと思っています。具体的に言うと、「node hoge.js」を実行するものです。あるいは、その中のJavaScriptのコードを実行できるものです。

今自分で調べている中で「GAS」が定期実行はできそうなので検討しています。

**定期実行するツールとして、なにかおすすめなどありますでしょうか？**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node.js を実行する Linux サーバーが手元にあるのであれば、[cron](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crontab) を使って定期実行するのが古典的です。JavaScript に限らず使われる手法です。

※ Windows サーバーの場合 cmd.exe における cron 的なコマンドとして [Schtasks.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/schtasks) が知られているようです。私は使ったことがありませんが補足まで。

※ Function as a Service (FaaS) である AWS Lambda や Cloud Functions を使い実行なさっている場合は、それぞれ CloudWatch Events や Cloud Scheduler を使って実現できます。

Answer (score 2):

要件で次第ですが、通常ジョブスケジューラを使うこともできます。
製品であれば、JP1、JobCenter
フリーであれば、Jenkinsなんかでも代替は可能です。管理したい対象が多くなったり、エラー発生時にアラーム鳴らすとかしたい場合に威力を発揮します。あとは複数ジョブの成否や実行待ちなどが必要な場合も便利に使えます。
単純に定期実行したいのであれば、cronやtaskスケジューラ使うこともできます。
どちらにしても要件次第です。